# Site design update

Tags: discussion, design

Hello Sharepoint SE community, our site got a slight design update today. I have moved site's CSS to a newly refactor LESS system, so it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally going on forward. Also I've updated site's logo and icons to SVG for retina support.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old CSS bugs. If you see any new ones, or old ones not being fixed, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

The site looks much more sleek. Good Job (Y)!